# How is this PHP/IFRAME file upload working?

Tags: php, ajax, iframe, file-upload

[Check out this link](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html).

How is the  code working out? I mean the `src` attribute of IFRAME is set to `#` then how does `upload.php` get to know that the form was submitted?

## Here is the code : `index.php` :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Max's AJAX File Uploader</title>
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function startUpload(){
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      return true;
}

function stopUpload(success){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
      }
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<label>File: <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" /><\/label><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';      
      return true;   
}
//-->
</script>   
</head>

<body>
       <div id="container">
            <div id="header"><div id="header_left"></div>
            <div id="header_main">Max's AJAX File Uploader</div><div id="header_right"></div></div>
            <div id="content">
                <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="startUpload();" >
                     <p id="f1_upload_process">Loading...<br/><img src="loader.gif" /><br/></p>
                     <p id="f1_upload_form" align="center"><br/>
                         <label>File:  
                              <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" />
                         </label>
                         <label>
                             <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" />
                         </label>
                     </p>

                     <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
                 </form>
             </div>
             <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.ajaxf1.com" target="_blank">Powered by AJAX F1</a></div>
         </div>

</body>   
</html>
```

---

## `upload.php` :

```
<?php
   // Edit upload location here
   $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

   $result = 0;

   $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

   if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
   }

   sleep(1);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>);</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have form action set to upload.php `<form action="upload.php"` hence when you submit upload.php knows form is submitted  (if i understand your question correctly then above line is true)

Comment: oops... silly thing should have read the code properly... my bad.. thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3):

The flow in this code is pretty simple if you follow the HTML form tag an it's related attributes. What is happening is the follwing:

1. Select upload
2. Submit form
3. The *onSubmit()* triggers a JS function which enables the loading.. visualization and disables the upload form. Because of the * return true*  the form is still submitted.
4. The form submit is done into the iFrame because of the 'target=' attribute. With that action you make the iFrame source 'upload.php'
5. Upload.php is called from within the iFrame.
6. The Upload.php result calls the main window JS function 'stopUpload' which informs on the rest of actions to take.

This script will work although it's result might change cross browser. This is a good script for a fast AJAX upload implementation.

Comment: I'd like to try this out, but I can't figure out - if you add another text field, checkboxes and so on, where does it say what file to submit the form to? For example, I have a file "put_form_results_in_the_database.php" and I want after the file upload submit the form results to that file. Where do I specify that?